# Python object array of empty arrays

Tags: python, numpy, dtype

I am attempting to create a numpy array of empty arrays without using loops. Using loops, I can use a simplified operation like

```
a = np.empty((3, 3), object)
for i in range(a.size):
    a.ravel()[i] = np.array([])
```

Or a marginally more sophisticated approach based on `np.nditer`:

```
a = np.empty((3, 3), object)
it = np.nditer(a, flags=['multi_index', 'refs_ok'])
for i in it:
    a[it.multi_index] = np.array([])
```

I can't seem to find an indexing expression that will allow me to make this assignment in a vectorized manner.

I've tried the following:

```
>>> a[:] = np.zeros((0, 3, 3))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0,3,3) into shape (3,3)
```

```
>>> a[..., None] = np.zeros((3, 3, 0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3,0) into shape (3,3,1)
```

```
>>> a = np.full((3, 3), np.array([]), object)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 343, in full
    multiarray.copyto(a, fill_value, casting='unsafe')
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in copyto
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0,) into shape (3,3)
```

Even `np.nditer` does not allow me to write back:

```
>>> a = np.empty((3, 3), object)
>>> for x in np.nditer(a, flags=['refs_ok'], op_flags=['readwrite']):
...    x[...] = np.array([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0,) into shape ()
```

Is there any way to make an object array of empty arrays in a vectorized manner?

The exact output I'm looking for is

```
array([[array([], dtype=float64), array([], dtype=float64), array([], dtype=float64)],
       [array([], dtype=float64), array([], dtype=float64), array([], dtype=float64)],
       [array([], dtype=float64), array([], dtype=float64), array([], dtype=float64)]], dtype=object)
```

For the purposes of this question, I don't care if the references are all the same array or different arrays.

Comment: How is your required output different from an array of shape (3, 3, 0)?

Comment: @ShlomiF: Completely different behavior on cell assignment, different shape, completely different memory layout, etc. For example, the desired array actually *has* contents, and you can do stuff like `a[0, 0] = 'asdf'` to store stuff in the array. Trying to do that with an array of shape `(3, 3, 0)` wouldn't store anything - it'd broadcast the assignment over a subarray of shape `(0,)` and store the string in the resulting 0 cells.

Comment: Hmm, good points...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get NumPy's broadcasting handling to treat an array as a scalar object instead of a source to broadcast from, by putting it inside *another* array:

```
template = numpy.empty((), dtype=object)
element = numpy.array([], dtype=float)
template[()] = element
```

Then you can perform a broadcasted assignment to store the `element` array in every cell of a result array:

```
result = numpy.empty((3, 3), dtype=object)
result[:] = template
```

The broadcasting logic will broadcast over `template` instead of `element`. This results in a 3-by-3 `result` array of object dtype, where every cell holds a reference to the single `element` array.

`result = numpy.full((3, 3), template)` would also work, but it seems even *more* confusing than the slice assignment, and the slice assignment is already pretty confusing - it's not immediately obvious whether the cells of `result` end up holding references to `template` or `element`.

Comment: All elements of `result` are the same object (same `id`).  Not it matters much, since there is little that one can do in-place to such an array.  Well, inplace reshape works: `result[0,0].shape=(0,2)`.

Comment: @hpaulj: Indeed. The question says that this is okay: "For the purposes of this question, I don't care if the references are all the same array or different arrays." The whole operation is weird enough that it's hard to say whether this aspect is weird in context.

Comment: So to avoid the OP's broadcasting problems, the object being assigned must itself be an object dtype array.